# read file, convert string to double, store in 2d array

Tags: java, string, multidimensional-array, double

I need to read a list of numbers in a file and store it into a 2d array.
This is what I have so far. How would I go about achieving this goal?

```
//this is only part of my code
public class RainFall
{

    double[][] precip;

    public RainFall()
    {
        precip = new double [5][12];
    }

    public void readFile(BufferedReader infile) throws IOException
    {
        FileInputStream infile = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(infile));

        String[][] myarray = new String[5][12];
        while (infile.readLine() != null) 
        {   
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    myarray[j][i] = infile.readLine();
                }

            }


        }
        infile.close();
    }
```

numbers.dat is 60 lines of:

1.01
0.03
2.14
0.47

Comment: post a sample of how your file looks like

Comment: How are the numbers separated on each line ? Can you give some sample data ? Is the quantity of numbers the same on each line ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Is each number on a new line? You're very close, I added a few lines below. 

    public class RainFall

{

    double[][] precip;

    public RainFall()
    {
        precip = new double [5][12];
    }

    public void readFile(BufferedReader infile) throws IOException
    {
        //FileInputStream infile = new FileInputStream("numbers.dat");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("numbers.dat"));
        String line = "";
        String[][] myarray = new String[5][12];

        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) 
        {   
            double num = Double.parseDouble(line.trim());
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++)
                {
                    precip[j][i] = num;
                }

            }


        }
        br.close();
    }
```

Comment: I also removed your use of FileInputStream, BufferedReader is all you need. This also is populating your 2d double array precip. If you want to populate your 2d String array myarray, you don't need the Double.parseDouble() call.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
String[][] myarray = new String[5][12];
```

use

```
double[][] myarray = new double[5][12];
```

Then sub this into the loop:

```
myarray[j][i] = Double.parseDouble(infile.readLine());
```